# What are the requirements to be able to run the Sims 3 with all expansions packs and custom items?

Tags: the-sims-3

**Below are a list of all The Sims 3 expansion packs in order of release ([source](https://help.ea.com/article/the-sims-3-installation-order)):**

- World Adventures
- High-End Loft Stuff
- Ambitions
- Fast Lane Stuff
- Late Night
- Outdoor Living Stuff
- Generations (May 31, 2011)
- Town Life Stuff
- Pets
- Master Suite
- Showtime
- Katy Perry's Sweet Treats Stuff
- Diesel Stuff
- Supernatural
- Seasons
- 70's, 80's & 90's Stuff
- University Life

Each packs adds various new items, and adds to the game.

**The minimum requirements for the base game are as follows ([source](http://www.thesims3.com/game/systemreq)):**

- 2.4 GHz P4 processor or equivalent
- 1.5 GB RAM
- 128 MB Video Card with support for Pixel Shader 2.0
- Microsoft Windows Vista Service Pack 1
- At least 6.1 GB of hard drive space with at least 1 GB of additional space for custom content and saved games

I've read that with each expansion pack that you install the longer load times will be (depending on your computer). I've looked at the specifications that are recommended, and my computer exceeds them however I'm skeptical. I'd rather not sink a lot of money on something that won't run well.

I figure that if I were to buy The Sims 3 plus all the expansion packs the minimum requirements would probably raise. **So what are the minimum requirements to run The Sims 3 with all of the expansion packs installed and possibly some custom content as well?**

Comment: The sims 3 is poorly optimized, it doesnt matter how powerful your rig is. the more expansions you throw in, the less playable it becomes. However, it is a VERY RAM and CPU intensive game. I would suggest at least 8gb DDR3 RAM at the minimum and a quad core CPU if you want to go for this.

Comment: @JLaBella Well my system requriements are linked in my comment [**here**](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/119429/what-are-the-requirements-to-be-able-to-run-the-sims-3-with-all-expansions-packs?noredirect=1#comment160960_119430). I think I can just about run it.

Comment: You should be able to play them all fine then.Expect slowdowns at times, though.

Comment: Lots of money. Lots of HDD space. Lots more money.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't speak to the exact requirements; but it seems to me that the requirements listed are severely underrated:

Running at 3.06 GHz, 8 GB RAM, 512 MB Video Card; The Sims is, even in base game, sluggish at 1680x1050.

The computational requirements, however, do **not** seem to increase with the various expansion packs, at least not to any appreciable degree, with the possible exception of Seasons.

Yes, loading times increase, but their oppressiveness is not much different going from base game to fully expanded.

In any case; if you have a 3 GHz+ processor and a 728 MB+ Graphics card, you *should* have it made.

---

#### Specifics

3.06 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo

8 GB 1067 MHz DDR3

NVIDIA GeForce 9600M GT 512 MB

Comment: I figured load times would be increase (you know extra content and etc). My computer specifications can be viewed [here on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/d00MgZpX) I guess I should be fine. As for the loading times maybe if I were to upgrade to an SSD that would help some?

Comment: @Scootaloo: Yeah, you should be fine. And yes, an SSD would absolutely help improve load times.

Answer (score 0):

The base game, plus late night and high end loft will run on 1.0GHz, as well as some of the others.  Seasons, I discovered, needs 2.something, or the game just won't play.  Also, be careful of windows 8.1.  I was told by EA tech support that it can be problematic with sims 3.