# Do I need the Sims 1 & 2 to play the Sims 3?

Tags: the-sims-3

I used to play The Sims years ago and I've  been thinking about buying the game again for my PC. If I buy The Sims 3 Starter Pack, is that all I need to get set up? Or do I need The Sims 1 to be downloaded onto my laptop first?

Comment: This seems to be a question that is opinion based as there is no one answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the requirements to be able to run the Sims 3 with all expansions packs and custom items?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/119429/what-are-the-requirements-to-be-able-to-run-the-sims-3-with-all-expansions-packs)

Comment: @DrFish I disagree. The Sims 3 and expansion packs are totally separate of the Sims 1&2. This question is asking if The Sims 1&2 are dependent for The Sims 3. Plus the question you linked is about system requirements.

Comment: It is about system & software requirements. And there is no mention of Sims 1 or 2 there, which sounds about the answer to this question

Comment: Yes that's what I'm asking is sims 1 and 2 required?

Answer (score 9):

Sims 3 is a full game in itself, so no need for older version.

Have fun playing :)

Comment: So If I buy it I should have no problem ?

Comment: @SophieHanafee, double check your laptop specs against the required specs for the game just in case (check out www.systemrequirementslab.com). But Sims games aren't very spec-intensive games, so odds are you'll be fine.

Comment: It may be also worth noting, if you didn't know already - that if you bought an expansion pack, that requires the full game to access.

Answer (score 1):

Sims 3 starter pack is all you need. Sims 1 and 2 are completely separate games. They aren't connected to each other.